# Remove Rproj file from git repository?

Tags: git, rstudio

I inadvertently pushed the RStudio `pkg.Rproj` file to my git repository, and now I'm afraid to pull it to another computer. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955689/should-i-check-an-rproj-file-created-by-rstudio-into-git) which says it's harmless, and maybe even desirable. But still I am not sure, because the file is created locally by setting up a project in RStudio. If the path to my project directory is different on a different machine, and that information is in `.Rproj`, then it'd be a mess.

Related, perhaps, is I added ther project file to `.gitignore`, but it still shows up in my Git window on RStudio.

What exactly is in an `.Rproj` file? Can anybody advise?

If I do need to remove it from my repository, is there a more elegant way to do it than copying it elsewhere locally, deleting it, pushing it (which may not work because of no `.Rproj` file), making a copy and then pulling it on my other PC, and restoring it on both machines?

Comment: Open the .Rproj file in a text editor. It's a human-readable YAML-like format and contains no paths AFAICS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `git rm --cached`. e.g.

```
git rm --cached pkg.Rproj
git commit -m "remove rproj"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also right click on the file showing on the git tab of rstudio and select ignore.